# How do Failable Initializers differ from Throwing Initializers?

Tags: swift

When I was reading into Throwing and Failable initializers, there was only one difference I could find: The fact that Failable returns nil, and Throwing throws an error. What I don't understand, is why the Failable would be used. It's better to throw errors, so I don't really see the point of returning nil when you could throw an error.

Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, I've just been pondering possible use cases for Failable Initializers, but everything I've thought of would be better handled with a Throwing one.

Comment: Failable initializers work nicely with optional binding, like `if let x = Int(myStr) { // use x }`.  It's sufficient when you don't need a detailed explanation of why it failed.  Error handling is a little more cumbersome to deal with.

Comment: So it is basically better for handling in some cases, since Error Handling isn't always necessary?

Comment: But your can example can be replaced with let x = try? Int(myStr) { // use x }, using a throwable initializer. To my mind, a throwable initializer gives the best of both worlds. Error-handling when you need it, optionality when you don't. Too bad Swift did not introduce try? before it had already introduced failable initializers.